# How to create custom elements, using web components?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, custom-element

I'm trying to create custom element ...

**My first option:**

JS:[image]

```
class AwesomeButtonComponent extends HTMLButtonElement {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.addEventListener('click', () => {
            alert('Great job!');
        });
    }
}

customElements.define('awesome-button', AwesomeButtonComponent, {extends: 'button'});
```

HTML:
`<awesome-button>CLICK ME</awesome-button>`

---

**My second option:**

JS:

```
customElements.define('awesome-button', Object.create(HTMLButtonElement.prototype), {
       extends: 'button'
    });
```

HTML:
`<awesome-button>CLICK ME</awesome-button>`

*08.07.2019* and `<button is="awesome-button">CLICK ME</button>`

> Each my attempt turns out a simple element. How to correct create custom element, which extended from native?

[image]

*js, vue, html5*

Comment: I wouldn't recommend you to extend HtmlButtonElement as Safari and Opera [don't support it](https://caniuse.com/#feat=custom-elementsv1), you should extend HtmlElement and have a button inside it or allow for button's to be inserted using a `slot`

Comment: Start by learning the basics in someone else his JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hasan3ysf/qzzs6yg0/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use customized built-in elements, you have to reference them differently (by using the `is`-attribute) [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#Customized_built-in_elements)

```js
class AwesomeButtonComponent extends HTMLButtonElement {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.addEventListener('click', () => {
            alert('Great job!');
        });
    }
}

customElements.define('awesome-button', AwesomeButtonComponent, {extends: 'button'});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Custom element</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button is="awesome-button">CLICK ME</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Be aware that not all browsers (as of 2019-07-08) support ["Customized built-in elements"](https://caniuse.com/#feat=custom-elementsv1) yet

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but nothing changed.

Comment: Which browser and which version are you using?

Comment: I've added a link to the browser-support of "Customized built-in elements"

Comment: I needed to create a custom element, for example “my-xextarea”, that would inherit from “textarea” and was absolutely the same, with the exception of the tag name. But it turns out that it is impossible to do it the way I wanted. Perhaps with internal content or with a shadow. Thanks.